# New Google Sign-In Implementation with App Engine Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

Google has just released a new way to let users sign in to an application with their google account:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Since it's recommended to use the new API, I'd like to do so. However, I'm not quite sure yet about some of the steps. It's clear to me how to implement the sign in workflow itself (the sample application is quite easy to understand). However, how do I get the API service handle for my backend service?

Until now, I used to do it like this: First, get a `GoogleAccountCredential` like this:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(
                context, "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);
credential.setSelectedAccountName("example@gmail.com");
```

Then, I passed these credentials on to the automatically generated android client library for the app engine endpoints:

```
User.Builder b = new User.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), CREDENTIALS_FROM_STEP_1).setApplicationName("App");
```

That was it. However, I have no idea how to get the `GoogleAccountCredential` when using the new sign in workflow. Has anyone got an idea? Do I need to update the backend as well? As I said, the whole OAuth2 communication and authorization with my backend is done by the auto-generated client libraries.